# MySQL SUM IF field b = field a

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  incMonth as Month, 
  SUM( IF(item_type IN('typ1', 'typ2') AND incMonth = Month, 1, 0 ) )AS 'Total Sales' 
FROM tester
```

I just need the sum for the current month its looping through.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish, what the problem is, and add an appropriate, meaningful title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm reading that right, you'd need to use a group-by or at least a where clause to restrict things to just the time range you're wanting:

```
SELECT incMonth AS Month, SUM(IF(item_type IN('typ1', 'typ2'), 1, 0)) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM tester
GROUP BY incMonth
```

Comment: Since TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0 you don't actually need an IF expression for this.
You can just do

    SELECT incMonth AS Month, SUM(item_type IN('typ1', 'typ2')) AS 'Total Sales'
    FROM tester
    GROUP BY incMonth