# MySql: is it possible to 'SUM IF' or to 'COUNT IF'?

Tags: mysql

I have a column 'hour'
I have a column 'kind'  (it can be 1,2 or 3)

I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT count(id), SUM(hour) as totHour, SUM( IF ( kind = 1, 1, 0 ) ) as countKindOne
```

or

```
SELECT count(id), SUM(hour) as totHour, COUNT( IF ( kind = 1 ) ) as countKindOne
```

But mysql tell me I've an error... what's the error!?

Please see this stackoverflow topic: [MySQL SUM IF field b = field a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083283/mysql-sum-if-field-b-field-a)

.. I'm not able to reply this ...

Comment: It's better to use `COUNT(IF(kind=1,1,NULL))` than `SUM(IF(kind=1,1,0))` because if you add a WHERE clause that returns no rows `COUNT` will return 0 but `SUM` will return NULL

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT count(id), 
    SUM(hour) as totHour, 
    SUM(case when kind = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as countKindOne
```

Comment: Use your logic with If `SUM(IF(o.id < 500000, 1, 0)) AS imported`

Comment: @Zohaib I like your approach more - it's shorter and clearer. Still +1 for solving the problem.

Comment: Its very neat solution for this.

Answer (score 101):

you want something like:

```
SELECT count(id), SUM(hour) as totHour, SUM(kind=1) as countKindOne;
```

Note that your second example was close, but the IF() function *always* takes three arguments, so it would have had to be `COUNT(IF(kind=1,1,NULL))`.  I prefer the SUM() syntax shown above because it's concise.

Answer (score 43):

You can also use `SUM + IF` which is shorter than `SUM + CASE`:

```
SELECT
    count(id)
    , SUM(IF(kind=1, 1, 0)) AS countKindOne
    , SUM(CASE WHEN kind=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS countKindTwo
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a slight difference between the top answers, namely `SUM(case when kind = 1 then 1 else 0 end)` and `SUM(kind=1)`.

When all values in column `kind` happen to be `NULL`, the result of `SUM(case when kind = 1 then 1 else 0 end)` is `0`, whereas the result of `SUM(kind=1)` is `NULL`.

An example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b23807/2):

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`first_col` int, `second_col` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`first_col`, `second_col`)
VALUES
       (1, NULL),
       (1, NULL),
       (NULL, NULL)
;
```

Query results:

```
SELECT SUM(first_col=1) FROM Table1;
-- Result: 2
SELECT SUM(first_col=2) FROM Table1;
-- Result: 0
SELECT SUM(second_col=1) FROM Table1;
-- Result: NULL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN second_col=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM Table1;
-- Result: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

From MYSQL I solved the problem like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN used = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amount_one,
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that you can build upon Gavin Toweys answer by using multiple fields from across your query such as

`SUM(table.field = 1 AND table2.field = 2)`

You can also use this syntax for `COUNT` and I am sure other functions as well.