# Mysql query for multiple fields values

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help with mysql query that show multiple fields based on their calculation.

I have the following data:

```
ID | Supplier | Total | Tax | Shipping | Paid
1  | 2        | 100   | 10  | 5        | 0
2  | 2        | 50    | 5   | 2.5      | 1
```

Now I want a result like the following:

```
Supplier | Total Paid  | Total Unpaid
2        | 57.5        | 115
```

My query as follow (so far)

```
SELECT suppliers.company, SUM(tax+shipping+total) as unpaid FROM poreceived LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = poreceived.supplierid WHERE paid = '0' GROUP BY supplierid
```

I don't now how to show the paid value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    supplierid,
    SUM(if(paid=1, total + tax + shipping, 0)) AS Paid,
    SUM(if(paid=0, total + tax + shipping, 0)) AS Unpaid
FROM poreceived
GROUP BY supplierid
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
    supplierid,
    total_paid + shipping_paid + tax_paid as Paid,
    amount - total_paid - shipping_paid - tax_paid as Unpaid
FROM (
    SELECT 
        supplierid
        total + tax + shipping AS amount,
        SUM(if(paid=1,total,0)) AS total_paid,
        SUM(if(paid=1,shipping,0)) AS shipping_paid,
        SUM(if(paid=1,tax,0)) AS tax_paid
    FROM poreceived
    GROUP BY supplierid
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using and IF inside the SUM

```
SELECT
t.supplier,
SUM(IF(t.paid = 1, t.tax + t.shipping + t.total, 0)) AS total_paid,
SUM(IF(t.paid = 0, t.tax + t.shipping + t.total, 0)) AS total_unpaid
FROM poreceived AS t
GROUP BY t.supplier;
```

This questions is a bit related:

[MySql: is it possibile to 'SUM IF' or to 'COUNT IF'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075505/mysql-is-it-possibile-to-sum-if-or-to-count-if)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot query to get the output you want:

```
SELECT Supplier,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Paid = 1 THEN Total + Tax + Shipping ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Paid`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Paid = 0 THEN Total + Tax + Shipping ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Unpaid`,
FROM poreceived
GROUP BY Supplier
```