# Select Query MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with six columns as following
`Home_Team | Home_Score | Away_Score | Away_Team | Home_Result | Away_Result`

I want to select the output of Home_Team record of win, loos & tie matches.

I used the following query however instead of counting individual totals it is showing count if all matches in each category.

```
select a.Home_Team,  
if(a.Home_Result = 'Win', count(a.Home_Result), 0) as Win,  
if(b.Home_Result = 'Loss', count(b.Home_Result), 0) as Loss 
from nsfa.result_main_bck as a  
join nsfa.result_main_bck as b   
on a.Home_Team = b.Home_Team  
where a.Home_Result = 'Win' and b.Home_Result = 'Loss'
Group by 1
```

What could be wrong in this code

I am using MySql by the way.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075582/285190 not sure why you are joining the table on its self

So something along the lines of

```
select a.Home_Team,
SUM(case when a.Home_Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end) as Win
SUM(case when a.Home_Result = 'Loss' then 1 else 0 end) as Loss
from nsfa.result_main_bck as a
where a.Home_Result = 'Win' or a.Home_Result = 'Loss'
Group By a.Home_Team
```

(NOT TESTED)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a.Home_Result = 'Win', count(a.Home_Result), 0) as Win,
```

It's a wrong approach rather yo should use `CASE` expression along with aggregate function like `SUM()`

```
sum(case when a.Home_Result = 'Win' then 1 else 0 end) as Win
```

Comment: My dear Rahul,  Thank for your response. However i am getting same result with your suggested command.