# How to do this query: multiple distinct counts

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the following rows (I am using a relational DB, so this is just a sample):

```
id, start_date, person, how_heard, status
```

Sample data would be like this:

```
1, 2017-01-01, bob, newspaper, attended
2, 2017-02-03, steve, mail, no show
3, 2016-04-12, mary, newspaper, no show
4, 2015-12-12, rick, mail, cancel
...
...
```

I now want to query this table to see the results of each marketing effort grouped by year.

So for 2017, I want to see that newspaper had 54 unique people and had 2 people attend their appointments, 0 no shows, 1 cancellation

So the columns for the report will be:

```
year, how_heard, total_appointments, number_cancel, number_no_show, number_attended
```

I am confused on how to do this.

Is this possible with one query?

Comment: Make an example with photos of your table and the wish result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql: is it possible to 'SUM IF' or to 'COUNT IF'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075505/mysql-is-it-possible-to-sum-if-or-to-count-if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You need to group by year and how_heard and have a conditional sum using a CASE statement for your other columns.  I've done the first one, the rest will be the same except changing the equals condition and column name

```
select year(start_date) year, 
  how_heard,
  count(1) as total_appointments,
  SUM(case when status = 'attended' then 1 else 0 end) as number_attended      

from campaign
group by year(start_date), how_heard
```

Find a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf75f2/1)

With your test data and the above query you get

```
year    how_heard   total_appointments  number_attended
2015    mail        1                   0
2016    newspaper   1                   0
2017    mail        1                   0
2017    newspaper   1                   1
```

Comment: Thanks, Dijkgraaf. That gave me the advice I needed to make this work. I appreciate it.  Didn't know I can make a fiddle like that either, so I'll be sure to do that next time I need help.