# Count number of occurrences of a value in MYSQL and group by ID

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has PersonID and Code columns. Each PersonID has multiple records each of which have a Code. I would like to count the number of occurrences of Code being equal to a specific value (say I want the number of times Code equals "R") for each PersonID. I'd like it to return it like this

> ((PersonID, Code_Count), (PersonID, Code_Count), (PersonID,
>   Code_Count), ...)

Could someone help me achieve this please?

Thanks.

EDIT: I think this is correct, can anyone confirm?
`SELECT PersonID,COUNT(*) as count FROM people WHERE Code="R" GROUP BY PersonID;`

EDIT: It doesn't include counts of zero but I added an answer below that solved that.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: yes you are good to go !

Comment: @Hasanalattar Turns out it's not quite there, please see my edit.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh ^

Comment: then you select distinct personid individualy and then left join the count for it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PersonID, CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Code = "R" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED) AS count FROM People GROUP BY PersonID;
```

This works completely as intended, thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for the partial solution.

Comment: Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you will get no rows for any non-matching `PersonID`.

I haven't tested this, but perhaps something like:

```
SELECT
  `PersonID`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `Code` = "R" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count`
FROM `People`
GROUP BY `PersonID`
```

By removing the condition, you don't elide non-matching Persons, but [with the `CASE` you're still only counting matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13075505/560648).

You should check whether this naive approach works at your expected scale with your indexes.

Comment: I think this almost does it, but it returns it like this: `Decimal('1')`, how can I just get it to return 1?

Comment: Sounds like that's a facet of your client's rendering/display logic, so we do not know enough (or, indeed, anything) about your environment to answer that. MySQL `SUM` gives you a number (or, in some other cases, `NULL`)