# Mysql query for sum of a field a if field b = "status"

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to get a mysql query working and need some help. I have 2 tables (staff, booking).

Staff table contains staff details

| StaffID | First_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |
| 2 | Mary | Doe |

Booking table contains

| BookingID | StaffID | Status | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | cancelled | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | ended | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | ended | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | cancelled | 30 |
| 5 | 1 | confirmed | 40 |

I am trying to get the total duration of ended booking for a staff. The current query I'm using is only able to get the total of all types of booking regardless of the status.

```
$status = "cancelled";
$query1 = "Select staff.StaffID, staff.First_name, staff.Last_name, sum(booking.duration) as duration, COALESCE(sum(booking.Status='$status'),0) as Status from staff LEFT JOIN booking ON staff.StaffID=booking.convenerID GROUP BY staff.StaffID";
```

This produces the table

| StaffID | StaffName | MeetingHours(min) | No. of cancelled meeting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 90 | 1 |
| 2 | Mary Doe | 30 | 1 |

However, I only want the meetinghours to be of ended meetings. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what about `Where booking.Status = 'ended'`?

Comment: @hassan adding this will cause the no. of cancelled meeting to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case statement in sum function to calculate only ended statuses

```
Select
    staff.StaffID,
    staff.First_name,
    staff.Last_name,
    sum(CASE 
    WHEN booking.Status = 'ended' 
    THEN booking.duration 
    ELSE 0 END) as duration,
    COALESCE(sum(booking.Status = 'cancelled'), 0) as Status
from
    staff
LEFT JOIN booking ON
    staff.StaffID = booking.ConvenerID
GROUP BY
    staff.StaffID
```

Comment: This does not work showing a error Unknown column 'booking.Status in having clause

Comment: @Vincent I`ve updatet my answer, check it please

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, it worked great never knew you could used nested case in sum().

Comment: It is atypical to nest the `SUM()` inside of `COALESCE()`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13075505/2943403